# Full screen mode automatically applies to my activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I have not implemented any styles nor themes to my activity only removed the title bar by calling

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But my activity automatically goes to immersive mode. This is what happens when i set

```
getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)
```

![This is what happens when i set getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7Yul.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check your theme property in android_manifest.xml.
Put proper theme and it should be alright

Comment: No theme added for this activity in manifest and application has a empty theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this property `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"` inside the `Activity` tag in manifest file.

I hope this will work for  you.